# How do I change the contents of a ListView in Scala?

Tags: user-interface, scala, listview

I'm trying to write a mini file browser, where I display a list of files, and replace the list by another when I change directories.

I can display a list:

```
val myList = List("Paris", "New York", "Tokyo", "Berlin", "Copenhagen")
val myListBuffer = new ListBuffer[String] ()
myListBuffer.appendAll(myList)
val myListView = new ListView(myListBuffer)
...
contents += myListView
```

In response to an event, I want to change the displayed contents. Most of what I've tried makes the list "invisible" (but still responding to selection by up and down arrows)--sometimes by making elements invisible only when they are selected!

How do I update the ListView to reflect the new contents of the ListBuffer? Or can someone point me to an example of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
object LVTest extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = myListView
    size = new Dimension(200, 200)
  }

  val myListView = new ListView[String]() {
    val myListBuffer = ListBuffer("Paris", "New York", "Tokyo", "Berlin", "Copenhagen")
    listData = myListBuffer
    listenTo(mouse.clicks)
    reactions += {
      case e: MouseClicked => {
        myListBuffer += "Slough"
        listData = myListBuffer
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that does work. Also it gives me some new insights on how GUI code can be arranged. Thanks!

Comment: Since my code wasn't really a good example of arranging GUI code, I've updated it to make it a bit better

Answer (score 2):

Call `myListView.listData = myListBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks! It's actually
  myListView.listData = myListBuffer
but your answer was close enough.
(I have no excuse for not seeing 'listData' in the API for ListView, BTW--just blind, I guess.)

Comment: :) updated (..buffer) so that it corresponds with your question